# how to add summery comment as soon as a method is created

Tags: asp.net

How can I add  comment as soon as I create a method?

I know that when we create a method and when we type "///" then this comment will get appear.

Instead  comment should get added automatically when I hit "}" to complete a method.

Is there any way to do that? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically add XML documentation comments for methods and properties using the [GhostDoc](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) extension available for visual studio.